# How do I prove $\sec^2 \frac{a}{2}=\frac{2\sec a}{1+\sec a}$?

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck in the middle of proving this identity, please help!

$$\sec^2 \frac{a}{2}=\frac{2\sec a}{1+\sec a}$$

Comment: If you are not familiar with sec, change everything to cosine first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sec^2(\frac{A}{2}) = \frac{1}{\cos^2(\frac{A}{2})} = \frac{2}{1+\cos(A)}=2\frac{\sec(A)}{1+\sec(A)}$$

The last equality holds because you can divide both the numerator and the denominator by $\cos(A)$.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly where i got stuck! I can figure out the next step :/

Comment: What is $x$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: *cant figure it out

Comment: awesome, now I got it! wow ya'll are quick to help thanks!